# imagescale function while uploading file

Tags: php, upload, gd

I try to implement a very simple scale function while uploading the file to the server. My host has 5.5.38 php version and gd is included and is 2.1.0 version.

The upload function worked until I tried to use the scale function. Obviously I am doing the wrong way but honestly I don't know what I am doing wrong and after a lot of research i am here to ask for your help..
This is the code that i use to upload file and scale it:

```
$id2 = $_POST['hiddenId'];
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

// CREATE DIRECTORY

$dir = "gallery/g";
$dir .= $id2;
$dir .= "/";

$dir2 = '../../' . $dir;

if (!mkdir($dir2,0777,true));

$foldername = $dir;

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    /* DATA FOR DATABASE */

    $images = '';
    $images .= $dir;
    $images .= $_FILES['file']['name'];

    /* UPLOAD FILE */

    $fileupload = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    //$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds . $foldername . $ds;

    // FILE DIRECTORY

    $targetPath = '../../' . $foldername;

    // TRY TO SCALE IMAGE

    $imagenew = '';     // NEW VARIABLE
    $imagenew = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempFile);  // PASSING THE TEMPFILE
    $imagescaled = imagescale($imagenew, 800);  // SCALING THE FILE

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $imagescaled;

    // MOVE SCALED FILE TO THE SERVER
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    // UPDATE DATABASE

    update_gallery($id2,$images,$con);
}
```

i inspected the code with firebug but it returns no error so I don't know where to start to catch the error.. May you help me please?

Comment: "i inspected the code with firebug but it returns no error" - Check the PHP error log.  You won't see server-side errors in the client-side developer tools.

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry for my late reply. The error was all by me. I haven't red all the gd documentation correctly and so the code was incomplete... I solved the problem. I will update the code above and put [solved] in the title hoping it can help others coders

Comment: Post your fixed code as an answer instead of editing your question. You should be able to accept it, indicating to others it’s solved. Much better to use the site correctly ;-)